# Understanding certain phrases in the article "Footwall topographic development during continental extension"

Tags: terminology, tectonics

I am currently attempting to read the article "Footwall topographic development during continental extension". The article and its abstract can be found [here](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2003JF000115).

When reading the abstract, I have trouble comprehending some of the sentences. The highlighted phrases below are the ones I have the most trouble understanding:

*We show that patterns of catchment area, footwall relief, and catchment outlet spacing vary predictably and are related to the **growth of the range‐bounding normal fault array**. In this semiarid region, **full parsing** of footwall drainage area and removal of antecedent topography do not occur **until fault arrays grow beyond two crustal‐scale segments**.*

Is "growth of the range‐bounding normal fault array" related to the amount of displacement, i.e. do they mean that these things depend on the amount of displacement?

I do not really understand what "growth of a fault array" means. Are we talking about fault linkage, or displacement increase?

By "full parsing", do they mean breaching of the barrier made by the footwall, i.e. creation of drainage channels?

I have no idea what they mean by "two crustal-scale segments".